# The following javascript code gives output 6 . How the code is executed?

Tags: javascript

Why the output of the following code is not (1,2,3,4,5)?

```js
var x = 0;

while (x < 6) {
  x++;
}

document.write(x);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more clarity as to how you got the idea that the call to `document.write()` would be executed with each loop iteration when it's clearly outside the loop block...?

Comment: _"Why the output of the following code is not (1,2,3,4,5)?"_ - Why should it be like that? There's only one `document.write()` and that's _after_ the loop o.O

Comment: `document.write(x);` is outside the body of the `while`-loop, as indicated by the closing `}`. Hence it is only executed once, after the `while`-loop has finished.

Comment: @Stef Apologies if your interpretation of my comment is condescending in nature (it was not intended in such a way), but it remains unclear to me how this logical conclusion was reached and I'd like the OP to expound on it just a bit more. I find that a line of questioning like this helps the OP to learn to employ a somewhat whittled-down version of "rubber duck debugging", in the spirit of "teach a man to fish..." and all.

Comment: It's easy to forget what it was like to be at the start of a learning curve, where now simple-seeming things were once mystifying. The commenters here both asked a pointed question about how the OP came to form their expectation. Asked with the intent to teach, these are very good comments, IMO. Asked with a snarl, it's boorish. I'd be inclined to assume good motives by both.

Comment: @Stef, why did you read condescension into the comment? I did not. It's plainly a logical question. I'd also like an answer.

Comment: @Stef Is it the `...?` and/or `o.O` that you find condescending? Everything else in those comments is asking for clarification and don't come off as such at all (to me anyway). Or, to put it another way, I've seen _way_ more condescending comments on Stackoverflow 

Comment: @TimLewis Only a few seconds after posting their question, the OP receives two comments, both asking "Why would you think that?", without a "hello", but with "...", "clearly" and "o.O". If I was the OP I'd feel a bit jumped-on. Note that almost every single day, I see questions deleted only a few moments after they were asked, because they received two or three unwelcoming comments in a row. StackOverflow is an incredibly intimidating place for new users.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are only writing to the document once.

For this, you should probably use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```js
for (let x = 0+1; x < 5+1; x++) {
  document.write(x);
}
```

This says x = 0 + 1 = 1 (so it starts at 0), then for every x > 5 + 1 (the +1 is so it ends at 5) do this, then add 1 to x.

Simply: x = 1, then when x is over 5, it will write to the document, then it will add 1 to x to continue the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the loop is repeated, the value in the x variable is updated.
x++  increases the value of x by one unit
And you write the final value

Answer (score -1):

This example shows how to achieve this:

```
var x = 0;
let myArray = [];
while(x<6) {
  ++x; // We want x to start at 1
  myArray.push(x) // Add the new value of x into the array
}
const string = '(' + myArray.join(',') + ')'; // Format the output string by joining the array in a csv format and wrapping with brackets.
document.write(string);
```